# Best way to score current extremum in collection type

Tags: scala, max, min, scala-option

I’m currently a little tired so I might be missing the obvious.

I have a `var _minVal: Option[Double]`, which shall hold the minimal value contained in a collection of `Double`s (or None, if the collection is empty)

When adding a new item to the collection, I have too check if `_minVal` is either None or greater than the new item (=candidate for new mimimum).

I’ve gone from

```
_minVal = Some(_minVal match {
    case Some(oldMin) => if (candidate < oldMin) candidate
                         else                    oldMin
    case None         =>                         candidate
})
```

(not very DRY) to

```
_minVal = Some(min(_minVal getOrElse candidate, candidate))
```

but still think I might be missing something…

Comment: Why not just use the `min` method of Scala's great collections? `List(2.0, 1.2, 3.4).min` prints out 1.2

Comment: I don’t get how would that help me.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't. Maybe if I knew more about why you are calculating the new minimum by yourself I could answer your question...

Comment: @agilesteel it doesn't sound very efficient to traverse an entire collection when you only need to compare 2 values

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Simple: Because in my case `O(1)` during every insertion is better than `O(n)` on demand. /e: Luigi’s ninjapost says it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without Scalaz, you are going to pay some RY. But I'd write it as:

```
_minVal = _minVal map (candidate min) orElse Some(candidate)
```

**EDIT**

[Eric Torreborre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91522/eric), of [Specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs/)/[Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/) fame, was kind enough to pursue the [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) solution that has eluded me. Being a testing framework guy, he wrote the answer in a testing format, instead of the imperative, side-effecting original. :-)

Here's the version using `_minVal`, `Double` instead of `Int`, side-effects, and some twists of mine now that Eric has done the hard work.

```
// From the question (candidate provided for testing purposes)
var _minVal: Option[Double] = None
def candidate = scala.util.Random.nextDouble

// A function "min"
def min = (_: Double) min (_: Double)

// A function "orElse"
def orElse = (_: Option[Double]) orElse (_: Option[Double])

// Extract function to decrease noise
def updateMin = _minVal map min.curried(_: Double)

// This is the Scalaz vesion for the above -- type inference is not kind to it
// def updateMin = (_minVal map min.curried).sequence[({type lambda[a] = (Double => a)})#lambda, Double]

// Say the magic words
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._   

def orElseSome = (Option(_: Double)) andThen orElse.flip.curried
def updateMinOrSome = updateMin <*> orElseSome

// TAH-DAH!
 _minVal = updateMinOrSome(candidate)
```

Comment: `type mismatch; found : Double required: Option[Double]` (pointer on second instance of candidate)

Comment: I think you want
`_minVal = Some(_minVal map (candidate min) getOrElse candidate)`.

Comment: or `_minVal = _minVal map (candidate min) orElse Some(candidate)`, yeah.

Comment: I think this is closer to Daniel's intent: `_minVal map (candidate min) orElse Some(candidate)`

Comment: Umm, @huynhjl, i posted this exactly above you. Also, I second Luigi’s request for the scalaz version. I’m primarily not using it, because I think it will cause the “maybe I can revise my whole codebase now” syndrome ;)

Comment: @flying sheep, yeah , I see it now, but didn't see it when I wrote my comment 12 hours ago which was addressed to Blaisorblade.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an update to Daniel's answer, using Scalaz:

Here's a curried 'min' function:

```
def min = (i: Int) => (j: Int) => if (i < j) i else j
```

And 2 variables:

```
// the last minimum value
def lastMin: Option[Int] = None

// the new value
def current = 1
```

Now let's define 2 new functions

```
// this one does the minimum update
def updateMin = (i: Int) => lastMin map (min(i))

// this one provides a default value if the option o2 is not defined
def orElse = (o1: Int) => (o2: Option[Int]) => o2 orElse Some(o1)
```

Then using the excellent explanation by @dibblego of [why Function1[T, _] is an applicative functor](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/uh5w6N2eAHY/3Shf1295VpYJ), we can avoid the repetition of the 'current' variable:

```
(updateMin <*> orElse).apply(current) === Some(current)
```